# Widget opens for a second then automatically closes?

Tags: python, pyqt4, show

I haven been trying to make a simple widget appear when I click a certain button, but for some reason my widget keeps disappearing and I have no idea why. Below is the code that I have for the widget:

```
if button.pressed() == True: 
    box = messageBox(self.text)
    box.show()

class messageBox(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.message = text
        super(messageBox, self).__init__() 
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(250, 100)
        self.move(300, 300)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText(self.message.toPlainText())
```

When the button is pressed, I just want to display a widget with all the information inside self.text but for some reason my widget keeps disappearing when I click the button. If anyone could help that would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It disappears because it get's garbage collected. You create a box, but when your function finishes, the variable `box` is deleted and since nothing is pointing to the widget it gets garbage collected and disappears. You have to save a reference to the `box` and keep it somewhere. Example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class messageBox(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(messageBox, self).__init__() 
        self.message = text
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(250, 100)
        self.move(300, 300)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText(self.message) 

class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__() 
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Push')
        button.pressed.connect(self.on_button_pressed)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def on_button_pressed(self):
        self.box = messageBox('foo')
        self.box.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
mw = MainWidget('test')
mw.show()
app.exec_()
```

Also you shouldn't check `if button.pressed()` you should connect it's `pressed` signal to a function that will be called whenever the button is pressed (but I assume that snippet was just a pseudo code).

Comment: Hm, I guess I am just a bit confused. How does the code above save a reference to the messageBox class?

Comment: @user1871869 It saves it as a `self.box` attribute of the `MainWidget` class. Since the `MainWidget` will exist through the entire program, none of its attributes will be garbage collected.